# How do I convert a numeric matrix to a tensorflow data set in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow

I think this is a simple question...

I'm trying to build my first NN where I compare my results from a random forest, glm, and gbm to a tensorflow NN. I have a data.frame that I've converted into a matrix of numeric data... some columns are binary indicators and others have been scale()-ed.

I tried to run `feature_spec()` like it says to do in all the tutorials that are loading canned data, and I get the error

`Error in dataset_prepare(dataset, !!self$x, !!self$y, named_features = TRUE) :  Provided dataset is not a TensorFlow Dataset`

I've found the commands [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/reference/tfdatasets/#section-creating-datasets), and yes, I could save my matrix as a CSV and then read it back in using `make_csv_dataset()` but that seems a bit idiotic and inefficient.

So how can I convert a numeric matrix into a TensorFlow dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I overengineered the solution by converting to a matrix. Just leave the data as a data.frame and `feature_spec` works just fine.